# Post request object from Aspx page to classic Page

Tags: asp.net, post, asp-classic, request, httpwebrequest

I'm trying pass request objects from an ASPX page to Classic ASP page and wondering what the best method of doing this is please?

The current classic page is accessing the request object to get access to variables. I cant pass this as a query sting so instead was wondering if this were possible using a POST `HttpWebRequest`.

If so how can I pass the variables without appending them to the url?

Comment: You're talking basic HTTP the method doesn't differ by technology, just pass your variables via a `POST` request and retrieve them in the ASP page using `Request.Form("varname")`.

Comment: Most likely a dup of [HTTP request with post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4015324/692942)